# Where can I find a list of questions I've asked on Stack Overflow?

Tags: discussion, user-interface

I can't seem to find the navigation to the questions that I have posted to Stack Overflow.  As well as comments that I would have made on other questions.  Is there an area of the interface for this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Click on your profile icon, and about half way down the page on the left there is a 'questions' link.

Comment: Thanks,  I also see there's a Newest sorting button to the right once I found it